# create input for sankey diagram

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an input table that looks like

[image]

There is no unique key. What is unique is the id and year combination.

I would like to create a sankey diagram to visualise the flow of ids from one bin to another for two selected years. The table that would feed the sankey would look like

[image]

where, e.g. year 1 can be selected to be 2014, and year 2 can be selected to be 2016.

How can we achieve this within powerBI? I could calculate the sankey input table outside powerBI, but this would not be very elegant, because the information is already available in the input table.

A possible solution would be to join the input table to it self using the id (many to many relation), filter for year 1 (coming from the left part of the join) and year 2 (coming from the right part of the join) using pick lists in the report, and finally counting ids in bin 1 (year 1) (coming from the left part of the join) and bin (year 2) (coming from the right part of the join) combinations.

Are such operations possible in powerBI and how?

I would prefer to use the sankey extension (https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380777?src=office&tab=Overview) from powerBI and not develop the sankey in python (I imagine this would break the interactivity).